# Not all songs synching on my Android smartphone when using Banshee

Tags: banshee

I have multiple playlists (about 2k songs) in Banshee that I want to sync with my Android smartphone (Motorola Milestone). The sync worked flawlessly from the start to the end but after looking at the result I noticed that some songs were missing on the Android device. After looking closer to the problem I saw that only songs that had a special characters in the name (&, /, +. etc) were not synched.

Are there other people having this problem and has anyone found a solution? Preferably one that does not consist in changing song names :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not just a Banshee problem, most syncing programs - rsync for example - also chokes when certain special characters exist within file names.  And that's the issue, it's filenames, not song names that cause problems - song names are recorded in metadata.  Knock up a shell script that replaces these special characters in the filenames, rescan and everything should look the same but should now sync without issue.

Regards,
Simon.